# Render text that is asynchronously received in Angular template

Tags: angular

When I retrieve data in an async manner as below:

```
font: string;

async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
  this.font = await BuilderSidebarTextService.renderGoogleFontToSvgPath();
}
```

How would then render it in my template?

```
<div [innerHTML]="font"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DomSanitizer` to sanitize the html as below,

```
  import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
  import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 
  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    const response = await BuilderSidebarTextService.renderGoogleFontToSvgPath();
    if(response){
       this.font = this.transform(response);
    }
  }

  transform(value: string): SafeHtml {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
```